# Why the Column header and TD width doesn't same in datatables?

Tags: html, css, datatable, datatables

I have this table in normal condition that i already set the width.
[image]

But when i add long text in the TD, the TH width and TD width doesn't same,
[image]

As you can see the width of TH smaller than the TD width.
This is the code i used to fixed the width,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table_id').DataTable( {       
            scrollX:        true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            autoWidth:         true,  
            paging:         true,       
            columnDefs: [
            { "width": "50px", "targets": [0,1] },
            { "width": "300px", "targets": [2] }
            ]
        } );
    } );
```

Do you know what is the problem?
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS table-layout Property with a fixed value.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp